# Create single JSON string from 2 JSON object with keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

So I have two objects:

Object 1:

```
{
  "Details": {
    "name": "John"
    "age": 34
  }
}
```

Object 2:

```
{
  "MoreInfo": {
    "Title": "Mr"
  }
}
```

I want to create one JSON object from these two objects that will look something like this:

```
{
  "Details1": {
      "Details": {
          "name": "John"
          "age": 34
      }
  },
  "Details2": {
      "MoreInfo": {
          "Title": "Mr"
      }
  }
}
```

I have tried various different methods( converting to dictionaries and merging, appending extra string {) but I can't seem to get around this.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Both of theses "JSON objects" are `NSString` or `NSDictionary`. You need to use a NS(Mutable)Dictionary and add the key (Details1 or Details2) with the corresponding value (a NSDictionary). Then convert it to JSON with `NSJSONSerialization`. If both of theses objects are `NSDictionary` use `NSJSONSerialization` before to translate them from `NSString` to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @Larme I literally just came across this while reading the docs for NSMutableDictionary! Thanks anyways will give it a go!

Comment: *Something like this* (dictionaries with only one key-value pair) is very inefficient. Put the keys `Details` and `MoreInfo` on the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use a mutable dictionary...

```
NSDictionary *details1 = @{
                           @"Details": @{
                                   @"name": @"John",
                                   @"age": @34
                                }
                           };
NSDictionary *details2 = @{
                           @"MoreInfo": @{
                                   @"Title": @"Mr"
                                }
                          };
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{
                                                         @"Details1": details1,
                                                         @"Details2": details2
                                                        }
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:nil];
NSLog(@"\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Outputs

```
{
  "Details2" : {
    "MoreInfo" : {
      "Title" : "Mr"
    }
  },
  "Details1" : {
    "Details" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "age" : 34
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think may this lines of code help you

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"name": @"John",@"age": @34 };
NSDictionary *userMoreInfo = @{ @"Title": @"Mr", };

NSDictionary *Details = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:userInfo forKey:@"Details"];
NSDictionary *MoreInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:userMoreInfo forKey:@"MoreInfo"];

NSMutableDictionary *finalDictThatWants = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[finalDictThatWants setObject:Details forKey:@"Details1"];
[finalDictThatWants setObject:MoreInfo forKey:@"Details2"];
```

Comment: Why use three different ways to create dictionaries? Be consistent.